# activerecord3 IN statement with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This must be super basic, but I just can't figure it out. I want to select from a table with lots of tag names all the tags who aren't part of the array 'tagnames'. I tried:

```
Tag.where(
  "name != ?", tagnames
)
```

gives me "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

```
Tag.where(
  "name NOT IN ?", tagnames
)
```

gives me a SQL error

I know how to get all entries with the names of tagnames:

```
Tag.where(
  :name => tagnames
)
```

just not how to say this inverse... Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to put the brackets round the `?` in your `"name NOT IN ?"` i.e. `"name NOT IN (?)"`. I expect that is the cause of your SQL error.